# Fragment inside another fragment doesn't call onResume() and onPause()?

Tags: android, android-fragments, kotlin

I have an activity initializing `FragmentA` and `FragmentA` contains `FragmentB`.

So when I replace `FragmentA` with some `FragmentC`, the `onPause()` and `onResume()` function of `FragmentB` is not getting called.

And, when I return back to `FragmentA`, FragmentB's `onPause()` is getting called before `onResume()`.

Here is my activity sample code  :

```
    class MyActivity : Activity() {
        override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
                val myFragmentA = FragmentA()
                fragmentManager
                        .beginTransaction()
                        .replace(R.id.fragContainer, myFragmentA, FRAGMENT_A_TAG)
                        .commit()
        }
      }
   }
```

Here is my Fragment sample code :

```
    class FragmentA : Fragment() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        // loading fragmentB
        fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragBContainer, FragmentB()).commit()

       }
        override fun onViewCreated(view: View?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
            super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
            //my layout changes

        }
    }
```

Fragment B : -

```
    class FragmentB : Fragment() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        //Todo -- empty

       }
        override fun onViewCreated(view: View?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
            super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
            //my layout changes

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason that `Fragment B` isn't calling it's `onResume` or `onPause()` is because it is not being added to the view properly. If you want to nest fragments you need to use `getChildFragmentManager()` instead of the regular `FragmentManager()` when managing the nested fragments:

```
getChildFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragBContainer, FragmentB()).commit()
```